# Input Dinâmico com JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Estou precisando inserir em um sistema um `<input>` com as seguintes características:

1. Deve ser um input.
2. Conforme digito, ele já busca informações previamente inseridas no sistema.
3. Caso não tenha encontrado, esse campo será inserido.
4. Deve permitir inserir "espaço", já que este campo é para inserir nome de pessoas.
5. O mais importante: só pode permitir inserir um único dado.

Já encotrei uma solução similar com **select2**, mas a função que permite inserir um campo quando não é localizado previamente não permite inserir espaços (similar ao campo TAGS aqui no Stack Overflow)

Além disso, preciso bloquear para que seja possível inserir apenas 1 campo por `<input>`

Comment: Qual código você tem até o momento?

Comment: Estou usando um `<input class="select2-ubi">`, com o seguinte jquery:
`$(".select2-ubi").select2({
  tags: true,
  maximumSelectionLength: 1
});`
Porém, ele não traz os resultados para eu selecionar... Aparece o seguinte: You can only select 1 item

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e coloca o HTML e o JS no código

Comment: Você tambem pode fazer isso com angular (autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**:

```
<select class="form-control demo-select2-3" name="pro_add_colaborador_3">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <?php
        $search_contributors = $pdo->query("SELECT con_id, con_nome_completo 
                                            FROM contributors 
                                            WHERE con_cod_cliente IN($accounts_src)
                                            ORDER BY con_nome_completo"); 
        $search_contributors->execute();
        while($res_contributors= $search_contributors->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $res_contributors['con_id']; ?>"><?php echo $res_contributors['con_nome_completo']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".select2-ubi").select2({
    tags: true,
    maximumSelectionLength: 1
});
```